# How can I display results from SQL query as custom values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a real simple question I was hoping to get help with.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
prescription.PRE_ID AS `Prescription ID`,

redeemed_prescriptions.PRE_ID AS `Redeemed`

FROM prescription
LEFT JOIN redeemed_prescriptions ON prescription.PRE_ID = redeemed_prescriptions.PRE_ID;
```

And here is the result:

```
Prescription ID | Redeemed
---------------------------
1               | 1
2               | NULL
3               | 3
4               | NULL
5               | NULL
```

As you can see,  when there is a match (i.e. the prescription has been redeemed) the matching number appears in the row, otherwise NULL.

My question is how can I make it so that when there is a match it displays 'True' and when there isn't a match it displays 'False' in the query output.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case statement` to display `True` when there is a match and `false` when there is no match

```
SELECT prescription.PRE_ID AS `Prescription ID`,
       CASE
         WHEN redeemed_prescriptions.PRE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'False'
       END                 AS Redeemed
FROM   prescription
       LEFT JOIN redeemed_prescriptions
              ON prescription.PRE_ID = redeemed_prescriptions.PRE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had looked at the case statement before but was struggling to figure out where to actually put it in the query.